# Jenkins maven projects ignore "Goals and options" specified in project "Build" section

Tags: maven, jenkins

The versions of my system are the following:

- Jenkins ver. 1.633
- Ubuntu version 14.04.2 LTS
- Maven version 3.0.5

I have configured the Maven settings under "Manage Jenkins"-->"Configure system".

When I create an "Invoke top-level Maven targets" step in the "Pre Steps" section everything works as expected. In the "Goals" line I can specify "-X", "clean install", etc. and maven picks this Goals up by printing for example :

> [DEBUG] Reading global settings from .../settings.xml
>
> [DEBUG] Reading user settings from .../settings.xml
>
> [DEBUG] Using local repository at .../repository

When I set the same goals (for example -X) in the "Goals and options" input field of the "Build section" I get only the following Jenkins console output:

> Parsing POMs ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
>   org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were
>   encountered while processing the POMs: [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent
>   POM: Failure to find nl.icscards:ics-build-parent:pom:1.1.8 in
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10
>
> at
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:364)
>     at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:361)
>     at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.readProjects(MavenEmbedder.java:331)
>     at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1301)
>     at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1098)
>     at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:991)   at
>   hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:969)    at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:960)
>     at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:679)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)  at
>   hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)    at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408) Finished: FAILURE

What I expect by specifying "-X" is to get some debugging information the same way as I do when invoking "Invoke top-level Maven targets" as a pre build step like I've shown above.

Please also note that everything works as expected as well if I create a "Freestyle project" instead of a "Maven Project" and execute there a shell statement of the form

`cd <job_workspace>
mvn -X clean install`

Also in this case I can see the expected output.

Any suggestions of what could be wrong in my "Maven project" jenkins configuration?
Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was that maven could not find the parent pom which is an external dependency to the project.

The strange thing is that a Maven Jenkins project tries to get these dependencies even before maven can print debug information like which settings file it uses on the jenkins console. Therefore it fails, but it is difficult to guess what the issue is. I thought that it couldn't pick up the right repository path or the right settings.xml file.

In my case the issue was that in the parent pom dependency in the repository I have a file

```
parent.pom.lastUpdated
```

which contains a line:

```
http\://<private-VPN-host>/repo/repo-central/.lastUpdated=1439803113007
```

From the jenkins server I don't have access to the private VPN host and therefore it fails. Removing that file or the above line solves the problem.
The dependency is than correctly picked up and the maven project builds correctly.